# SSRS Report Manager rules for generating Models from Data Source with plural table names

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, singular, plural

I am using the SSRS Report Manager web interface to generate Data Models for a SQL Server 2008 R2 Data Source.

The database contains a number of tables with names which are plurals. In the generated Data Models, the corresponding entities have names which have been transformed to a singular form.

Is it possible to disable this functionality?

Comment: As far as I know this is by design and can't be changed

Comment: After plenty of Googling, I was pretty sure that was the case. I was unsure as I struggled to find documentation that explicitly stated it.